# Using java or javascript instead of Google app script

Tags: java, javascript, google-apps-script

From Google app script ([https://developers.google.com/apps-script/),I](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/%29,I) got this:-

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create('Hello, World');
// Access the body of the document, then add a paragraph.
doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This document was created by Google Apps Script.');
// Get the URL of the document.
var url = doc.getUrl();
```

What I would like to do is to be able to duplicate this from my javascript or java code so I can create a doc and get its URL.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk).

Comment: Thanks Andrew.I know that i will use Google Drive API but how i can use it inside my java code or java script pages?

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the web: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js

Comment: Thanks Andrew:) but How to use this line of Google script :var doc = DocumentApp.create('Hello, World'); in my javascript code and alert the value doc.Did you got what i need to do?Is to use my javascript page instead of running app script.